# Placing a picture in a column

Tags: graphics

I would like to insert a picture into my column and not on a new page or spanning both columns. How would this be done.

Comment: `\includegraphics{..}` is just positioned like a letter, so your question is the same as asking to put `hello` into a column. `\includegraphics` has no spacing commands at all it does nothing to force a page break or span columns. If you have some code that isn't working as you expect you need to show the code,

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a layout that includes an image which stays in its own column and does not span columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} % or letter or a5paper or ... etc
\usepackage{multicol} % For the layout in columns
\usepackage{graphics} % This is what you need for inserting the picture

\title{ONE MIRACLE AFTER ANOTHER: The Pavel Goia Story}
\author{Greg Budd}

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

{
\center
Chapter 1: Say Not, I Am a Child\\
}

\begin{multicols}{2}

``I don't believe there is a God!" Pavel Goia blurted into the darkness.  ``I'm tired of the whole foolish notion.  I feel as if I'm going crazy!  How could I have allowed myself to be duped?  Believing in a Being who doesn't even exist has stolen all the fun from my life.  My friends are out having the time of their lives while I lie here feeling lost and condemned.  How many more nights do I need to toss and turn without sleep?  I hate listening to the seconds ticking endlessly away.  Lying here with thoughts of guilt echoing and reechoing through my mind feels like a nightmare.  I would give anything to silence that haunting Voice: ``Pavel, if you die tonight, you'll be lost forever!"\\

One thought after another bombarded the troubled young man attempting to escape the torture of his soul.  Poor Pavel--he had no place to run and nowhere to hide.  But he had made up his mind to bring his misery to an end.  ``I have to put these crazy ideas about God behind me and just enjoy life the way all my friends do," Pavel said half aloud as he pulled the covers aside.\\

``That does it.  I'm going to town to have some fun--I can't sleep anyway," he muttered under his breath as he scanned the room for his pants.\\

Attempting to find his clothes in the shadows of a darkened room was not an easy task, but with a little persistence he succeeded.  Carefully calculating his escape, he tiptoed from room to room so as not to awaken his parents.  But when he reached the living room, he stopped in his tracks.  The moonlight shining through the window outlined the silhouette of his father kneeling in prayer.  Pavel had often happened upon his father in prayer, but why tonight?  His praying father was the last thing his troubled mind desired to see as he made his escape from home and his parents' God.\\

% THE FOLLOWING LOOKS IN THE SAME DIRECTORY 
% AS THE .TEX FILE FOR THE IMAGE.
% A MORE COMPLETE PATH MAY BE NEEDED 
% IF THE IMAGE IS SOMEWHERE ELSE.

\includegraphics{images-37.jpeg}

His pace quickened as he stepped out into the darkness.  From the dim lights lining the street, he glanced in the direction of shadowy objects stretching out before him.  The haunting image of his father praying followed him from shadow to shadow as he hurried to the city and his waiting friends. \\

``Hey, Pavel! Glad you could make it!" called one of his friends with a bit of a slur as he approached their usual hangout. . . .\\

\end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

That results in the following output:

[image]